# Button cannot shown in android 2.2

Tags: android, android-layout

Recently I created an android app and in this app introduction pages for my application are included. In introduction page, I added the button dynamically as "next" and "finish". It can work well on android version 4.1.2 but when I run on android version 2.x, the buttons are not appeared. Can anybody answer me? The following are some of my source code.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_screen_slide, menu);

    menu.findItem(R.id.action_previous).setEnabled(
            mPager.getCurrentItem() > 0);

    // Add either a "next" or "finish" button to the action bar, depending on which page
    // is currently selected.
    MenuItem item = menu.add(
            Menu.NONE,
            R.id.action_next,
            Menu.NONE,
            (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1) ? R.string.action_finish : R.string.action_next);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
            | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    return true;
}
```

The following is my value/ids.xml

```
<resources>
<item type="id" name="action_next" />
<item type="id" name="action_flip" /></resources>
```

Comment: are you extending you class with "Activity" or "ActionBarActivity"?

Comment: @Jigar I extend fragmentActivity. Is it a problem?

Comment: And android device below API 11 does not support actionbar if you extend your class with "Activity". If you want to access you actionbar for the devices below "API 11 and upto API 8" than you can do it by using "ActionBarActivity". Check this developer's explaination on how to use actionbar for the API below 11.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: If you want to use actionbar for the API below 11 than you have to use support library for which i have given link above on how to setup support library and how to get actionbar for API level below 11 to use actionbar functionalities using "ActionBarActivity"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna use Fragments in Android devices < 3.0 you need to use the compatibility libraries provided by Google.

> - Open Android Studio
> - ToolBar->SDK MAnager Available Packages->Android
> - Support package (install this)

Jump to your app folder inside your module and open the **build.gradle** file
add the following

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

instead of getFragmentManager() you must use getSupportFragmentManager